# Access Foursquare venues without Oath?

Tags: api, foursquare

Is it possible to use the Foursquare API without the Oath stuff? My iPhone app does not provide checkins or information about a users Foursquare account. I simply allow people to type in an address, in my iPhone app, and I want to access Foursquare to return places near the address.

So a user might type in "417 N. 8th Philadelphia, PA" and Foursquare should return a list containing "VentureForth, Philadelphia Traffic Court, etc...", which I then display to users as options to select from.

Do I need to require Oath from my app to do this? Is there a way to set this up on our backend so only our backend needs to complete one Oath instead of each user/app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Look at how to create [userless requests](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless). All you need to pass in are your `client_id` and `client_secret` as params.